# example of Developer defined package in java

Tags: java

i need an example in Developer defined package in java i cant find any example about it

as you know there are tow kinds of packages in java as the following definistion

Java Packages: The Java language provides the concept of a package as a way to group a number of related classes.
Types
– Standard Java Packages.
– Developer defined package.

brgd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "developer defined package" is not some special kind of package. What is meant in the text that you quote is that a "developer defined package" is simply a package other than the packages in the standard Java API (packages named `java.something`, `javax.something` etc.).

Any package that you create yourself is a "developer defined package". See this tutorial page to learn about using and creating packages:

[The Java Tutorials - Creating and Using Packages](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html)

Answer (score 0):

Go through the java tutorials.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html (and following).

Answer (score 0):

It is strange. 99.999% of code is created in user defined packages. Package is like directory. If you have source directory and want to create package `com.mycompany.myprogram` just create directories `com/mycompany/myprogram` under your source directory and then create classes there. I believe that you are using IDE. In this case it helps you to manage your packages. For example in eclipse you can perform right click and then choose New->Package.